# Adding items in <select> element using c#, javascript and HTML with sql server field

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql-server

Can someone help me solve this problem. I just want to add an Items in  element in html with database field using c# and javascript, but my code has no output. Also, I tried to input a button and Called the Function "loadGrp" on onClick property of the button. eg: input type="submit" value="Add Item" onClick ="loadGrp();" but also it does not work. how to fix this problem, i know someone out there has a capability to solve this, so please help me guys Guys..

JS

```
function loadGrp()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../WebService/wsLeaveRequest.asmx/LoadGroup',
        dataType: 'json',
        //data: '',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response){
            $('#cboGroup').empty();
            var cell = eval("(" + response.d + ")");
            for (var i = 0; i < cell.length; i++)
            {
                $('#cboGroup').append('<option value="' + cell[i].grpID + '">"' + cell[i].grpShortName + '</option>');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        complete: function () {

        }
    });
}
```

C#

```
  [WebMethod]
    public string LoadGroup()
    {
        List<GroupInfo> mylist = new List<GroupInfo>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spLoadGroup", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(dr.Read())
            {
                mylist.Add(new GroupInfo
                {
                    grpID = dr["groupID"].ToString(),
                    grpShortName = dr["groupShortName"].ToString()
                });
            }
            dr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsn = js.Serialize(mylist);
        return jsn;
    }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <script src="Script/jsSetting.js"></script>
        <script src="Script/jsleaverequest.js"></script>

                    <div class="row cells12">
                        <div class="cell colspan3">
                            <div class="input-control select full-size">
                                <h5>Filter Group:</h5>
                                <select id="cboGroup"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<body>
<head>

</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, debug your code and check that the C# method is returning a valid JSON object. Then console.log the response of the AJAX call and make sure it is what you expect.

Comment: Ok I'll do it Sir. Thanks for the Advice.

Comment: Sir? it did not fix the problem, same status of the project.

Comment: So you can confirm that the stored procedure returns the correct data and that the AJAX request gets the data back? When you console.log it you see the rows from the database? That at least means your issue is with placing the data into the `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of observations

1. `url: '../WebService/wsLeaveRequest.asmx/LoadGroup',`

   The `..` may not be making any sense here
2. If there is no form in the page then replace `input type = "submit"` with `input type = "button"`
3. `var cell = eval("(" + response.d + ")");` seems fishy. Using `eval` is not a good idea and specifically here it dont seems to make any sense.

Put a debugger or a log statement at the first line of `function loadGrp` and see if the function is getting executed on button click. Then check from developer's window(`For Chrome press f12 -> Click on network -> Hit the input type = button`)  and validate if it is making any network call and validate the response of it